# Как char преообразовать в unicode сhar?

Tags: objective-c, строки, c

Добрый день. Как char преообразовать в unicode сhar? Нужно мне это, чтобы потом в Objective C к классу NSString присвоить строку Си-шную, но NSString - это класс Objective C, char не понимает. Спасибо. Дмитрий.

Answer (score 1):

[NSString stringWithCString:"test string" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как в Objective C, но в обычном Си и С++ для этого используют функцию `mbrtowc` из `wchar.h`.